# Application.Properties file is not override during executing google cloud run job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have written a sample spring-boot application and I am fetching value from application.properties file.

Now here is the interesting thing suppose there is parameter in properties file as value = 100 now when I execute the program in google cloud Run JOB by [overriding](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#console_1) the values as value = 200 then it works
but suppose the parameter is like value.number = 100 in properties file then i tried to override it as value.number = 200 then it does not work it picks the default set value which is 100.

I am guessing there might be something wrong with the syntax I am specifying while overriding.

I also tried various syntax like value_number, "value.number", value-number but none of this works.

If you need anything, do let me know to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share how you invoke Cloud Run Job with override? and how you code use the properties?

Comment: problem solved @guillaumeblaquiere do you still want to know how did i invoke cloud run job with override.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some other syntax and correct syntax is VALUE_NUMBER (all caps) and use "_" to join. and same should be used in your application.properties file